# Can a JavaScript .execute command be run synchronously, or converted to Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, synchronous

I am using the ArcGIS API for Javascript found here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/index.html

This piece of JavaScript seems to run asynchronously, is it possible to make it run synchronously, or even convert it to synchronous Ajax ?

I can't seem to find much info on the .execute command

I need it to run synchronous so that PHP can scrape the result (final result will echo true or false, alert is just being used to debug)

```
var identifyTask = new esri.tasks.IdentifyTask("http://website.here");
var identifyParams = new esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters();
identifyParams.tolerance = 0;
identifyParams.returnGeometry = true;
identifyParams.layerIds = [layerID];
identifyParams.width = map.width;
identifyParams.height = map.height;
identifyParams.geometry = geom;
identifyParams.mapExtent = map.extent;

identifyTask.execute(identifyParams, function(results) {
    if (results.length == 0) {
        alert('true');
    } else {
        alert('false');
    }
});
```

Comment: Since `.execute` is not a native JavaScript function, you should at least explain what library you are using. When you work with asynchronous code, learn how to work with callbacks.

Comment: The only includes are - http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=2.5 and http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API Spec [Here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm) does not include a specification for a synchronous execution.

It works only with a callback and `onComplete` and `onError` events.

The `execute()` method is not a part of the Javascript standard library. Please note in your example code how you start out with `esri`. You are working with `esri`'s library. A quick google search for "esri javascript" found the API site and then browsing through the API found me what you are using in your code.

As for you stating that you wish PHP to scrape the results, you are not making much sense. This javascript is designed to run client side while PHP is a server side technology. Please further elaborate how PHP would be scraping the results and why this method being synchronous would have any bearing on this whatsoever.

Comment: ouch yeah I think your right! basically the only way to pull the data is via javascript. A true or false output needs to be read by PHP.. any ideas ?

Comment: one idea.. when the user posts their query in a form, it could run the script in an iframe, the results could then be submitted back to php. or is there a better way ?

Comment: that seems like an overly complex and error prone solution. If you need to talk to the ArcGIS service from PHP, look at their RESTful API here: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/rest/index.html. A quick google search shows some blog posts of people who are doing this already: http://jayantbsai.blogspot.com/2008/08/using-php-with-arcgis-server-93-rest_13.html

Comment: A geolocation can be found with their API, however I needed a specific result from one of their scripts that I couldnt duplicate. Ended up using the iframe solution and submitting the result to the parent url. Seems to work ok, sorry for the silly question (still learning JS!)

Comment: @Lamer, No worries we are all still learning. The best resource that I have found for Javascript, even if you don't use Firefox (I don't), is the MDN Javascript guide found here:  [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide)